# Seagate Momentus 7200 4 250GB HDD is not working anymore

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, physical-damage

I got the hard drive and when I plugged it in I heard it spinning and clicking but it won't work! In the past I tried the Acer laptop and it detected and booted to unsupported windows which was just given by my friend and now I formatted it and a fail! now I plugged it to the enclosure and now it won't open the files I tried to listen to see what was wrong and everything was fine so I used seatools from Seagate and it detected but more damage has happened and now it won't detect and I don't want to pay for recovery serivce to fix the drive and sending them away is there a solution? Edited with Grammarly.

Comment: Okay from what you've described, the only solution is probably to send it off to get fixed. Furthermore, from what I can tell, if you formatted the drive, there won't be any files on it. Formatting wipes the drive.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf but what can i do without sending my drives away?

Comment: I'm afraid there's not much you can do by yourself because the damage on the HDD is physical/hardware-raled, @watonis! :( A professional data recovery company would be your best bet on getting those files back. Although from what you explained, you might not even be able to do that. You can surely [try third-party utilities](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) but they are highly risky. Potentially they'll do more harm to the HDD, than good. If you try to tamper with it manually, it would again backfire and make it even harder for a professional service to assist you. Good luck!

Comment: @Kaizerwolf, «Formatting wipes the drive»... unless explicitly changed, the normal (aka quick) formatting process only erases the partition table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover lost/inacessible data from my storage device?](http://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inacessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As myself and SuperSoph_WD have said, there really is not much you can do at this point. Certain third party tools like [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva) or [MiniTool Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/) could help, but there are a few catches.

1. The drive could be unreadable in its current state, and as such, you would likely be wasting your time trying.
2. SuperSoph_WD said it; you will likely do more damage to the device and make it harder, if not impossible, for a professional service to assist you.
3. You claim to have formatted the drive, meaning all of your files are gone. Formatting erases the contents of a drive. Therefore, there are no files for your to recover, leading to that waste of time I mentioned in the first point.

The long and short of it is, there is not really another option other than to send the drive to a professional to see if they can recover files from it. Take this as a hard lesson; **always back up your data.**

Comment: i dont care because the guy dint need the drive at all he gave it to me beacuse he needs the ssd so hes also upgarding windows with new cd he said theres nothing important in it

Comment: i cant use recuva it failed and also opening from explorer just makes to not respond http://imgur.com/c1nebY2 im trying second tool

Comment: @watonis You don't seem to be grasping the answer here. There is no other way to recover your data at this point without building your own static-free cleanroom, and physically opening the HDD yourself, which I doubt you want to do. You will very likely need to send this or take it to a professional service to retrieve whatever data is on your drive. The drive is corrupt and broken, hence why explorer crashes and Recuva cannot locate anything.

Comment: im not opening it i have a lot of dust in my room so i found MiniTool Partition Wizard and its working im using long fix trick and it looks like its going well! ;) i will report what progress has happened and maybe i will not need to send my drive away!

Comment: «Formatting erases the contents of a drive» You should definitely specify the difference between low level formatting and quick formatting (the latter being the standard Windows formatting, that does not erase the drive).